# angular directive building a select has undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to get my head around the angular directives, basically, the directive i want to build is a simple html select builder with some predefined options. This works great.

But what i cannot figure out it, how to load the directive with an option preselected, but to also assign the select to any particular `$scope`.. the snippet below works but you need to predetermine the `$scope` name in the directive as opposed to dynamically by a directive attribute.

Currently the select is bound to `ngSelectDayMonth.day`, which is OK, but it would be more flexible if you could choose dynamically, to better fit with any controller. In the snippet below for example, to assign to value to `$scope.form_data`

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('dates', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {

    $scope.form_data = {};

    $scope.ngSelectDayMonth = {
      day: 5,
      dayChange: function() {
        alert($scope.ngSelectDayMonth.day);
      }
    };
  }
]);

myApp.directive('ngSelectDayMonth', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    controller: function($scope) {
      $scope.days = [];
      for (var i = 0; i <= 31; ++i) {
        $scope.days.push(i);
      }
    },
    template: '<select ng-model="ngSelectDayMonth.day" ng-change="ngSelectDayMonth.dayChange()"><option ng-repeat="day in days" value="{{day}}">{{day}}</option></select>'
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div class="ng-scope" ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="dates">
    <ng-select-day-month ng-model-day="ngSelectDayMonth.day"></ng-select-day-month>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to make your directive reusable and set your predefined values is to use two way binding with an isolated scope and a link function:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('ctrl1', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {
    $scope.formData1 = {};
    $scope.startingValue = 3;
  }
]);

myApp.controller('ctrl2', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {
    $scope.formData2 = {start:{}, end:{}};
  }
]);

myApp.directive('ngSelectDayMonth', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      startingValue: "=",
      selected: "=day" 
    },
    controller: function($scope) {
      $scope.days = [];
      for (var i = 0; i <= 31; ++i) {
        $scope.days.push(i);
      }
    },
    link: function(scope) {
      scope.selected = scope.startingValue;
    },
    template: '<select ng-model="selected" ng-options="day for day in days">{{day}}</select>'
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <h3>controller 1</h3>
  <div ng-controller="ctrl1">
    <ng-select-day-month day="formData1.day" starting-value="startingValue"></ng-select-day-month>
    {{ formData1 }}
  </div>
  <h3>controller 2</h3>
  <div ng-controller="ctrl2">
    <ng-select-day-month day="formData2.start.day"></ng-select-day-month>
    {{ formData2.start }}
    <ng-select-day-month day="formData2.end.day" starting-value="10"></ng-select-day-month>
    {{ formData2.end }}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I was going around in circles trying to figure that one out